# Pass vars to other method javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, inheritance

I want to pass var "firstWord" with saved value in it from one method to another.

```
var obj = {

    getWords: function () {

        var words = [];

        $('input').each(function () {
            words.push($(this).val());
        });

        var firstWord  = words[0],
            secondWord = words[1],
            thirdWord  = words[2];

    },

    pushWords: function () {

        Array.prototype.insert = function (index, item) {
            this.splice(index, 0, item);
        };

        var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"],
            randomPosition = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (5 - 2 + 1)) + 1);

        fruits.insert(randomPosition, firstWord);


        $('body').append(fruits);
    }

};
```

Probably my code is wrong a bit, but is there any possibility to do that in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a varible with the `var` keyword, it's a only available in the function. Leave it out and you'll have a global variable, which you can access from other functions as well. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Answer (score 0):

One way it to pass one function's value to the other, like:

```
function one(){
var var1 = "hello";
two(var1);
}

function two(x){
alert(x);
}
```

This should print "hello" for you.
The other way is to declare your firstWord as a global variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to return the array like below,

```
 getWords: function () {

        var words = [];

        $('input').each(function () {
            words.push($(this).val());
        });

       return words;

    },
```

and in push words

```
    pushWords: function () {

            var arr = this.getWords();
            ................
            ................
            ................
           fruits.insert(randomPosition, arr[0]);
    }
   $('body').append(fruits);
```

since var firstword,secondword and thirdword are only accessible inside the getwords function you must try to return it. And don't forget to validate the 
return value before you use it. Hope it helps..

See example here https://jsfiddle.net/xz0ofkjx/

Answer (score 0):

So make it a property of the object.

```js
var obj = {

  _words : [],
  
  setWords : function () {
     this._words = ["hello","world"];
  },
    
  pushWords : function () {
    this._words.push("foo");  
  },
    
  readWords : function () {
      console.log(this._words); 
  }
  
}

obj.readWords();
obj.setWords();
obj.readWords();
obj.pushWords();
obj.readWords();
```